# Length of Component.find() getting updated unexpectedly

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Scenario:
I have two picklist 'Description' and 'Status'. If 'Description' is blank and 'status' is changed to 'Done' value, it will show an error message and error message should disappear if 'Status' is changed back to 'Open'.(both of these scenario is working), and if 'Status' is again changed from 'Open' to 'Done', it should show the same error message(this is not working).

Reason- it is not working because `component.find('question_answer').length` is getting updated to `2` when 'Status' is changed from 'Done' to 'Open'.
Question- Cannot figure out why is it getting updated?
Component

```
//1st picklist--Description
<aura:if isTrue="{!question.Answer_Type__c == 'Picklist'}">
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.isVisible}"> //this is used to rerender description picklist
<lightning:select value="{!question.answer}" name="{!question.Id}" aura:id="question_answer" onchange="{!c.changevalue}" required="false" messageWhenValueMissing="{!$Label.c.Answer_Required}">
<option value="">{!$Label.c.FAQ_Please_Select }</option>
<aura:iteration items="{!question.answers}" var="answer">
<option value="{!answer.value}" text="{!answer.label}"></option>
</aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
</aura:if>

//2nd picklist--Status
<lightning:select name="status " label="Status" value="{!v.selValue}" 
onchange="{!c.questionStatusChange}">
<option value="Open">Open</option>
<option value="Done">Done</option>
</lightning:select>
```

Controller:

```
questionStatusChange : function(component, event, helper) { 
   let questions = [];
    let quesLength = component.find('question_answer').length;// this returns undefined when status value is changed for the first time
which is expected since there is only one item in question_answer
but returns 1 when status is changed from 'open' to 'Done' for the 2nd time(not expected)
    if(quesLength === undefined) { 
        questions.push(component.find('question_answer'));
    }
    if(component.get("v.selValue") == 'Done') {// when status is changed to Done
        for(var ques in questions) {
            if(questions[ques].get("v.value") === null || questions[ques].get("v.value") === undefined || questions[ques].get("v.value") === '' ) {
                questions[ques].set("v.required", true);
                questions[ques].showHelpMessageIfInvalid(); //displays error message
            } 
        }

    } else {//when status is changed to open
        for(var ques in questions) {
                questions[ques].set("v.required", false);
                console.log(component.find('question_answer').length);//this still returns undefined as expected
                // setting 'isVisible' to false and then to true to remove the error message

                component.set("v.isVisible", false);  
                component.set("v.isVisible", true);
                console.log(component.find('question_answer').length);//this returns 2, not expected
            }           
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

`lightning:select` does not have proper validity handling. I would recommend to use `lightning:combobox` instead.

You can show/remove validity like below:

```
clear : function (component, event, helper) {
    component.find("select").set("v.required",false);
    component.find("select").reportValidity();
},
showError : function (component, event, helper) {
    component.find("select").set("v.required",true);
    component.find("select").reportValidity();
},
```

Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:combobox/specification

**REASON FOR ABOVE**

I have come across this situation quite few times. We face this situation when a component is unrendered and again rendered immediately.

**Reason**:

Aura framework creates DOM at runtime. So, when an element is unrendered, it will be removed from visible DOM by `aura_prod.js` and also it will remove internal references to that element. Again when the element has to be rendered, the library will create it and references are added. This function of creation and destruction is async in nature.

So, when you run below code:

```
component.set("v.isVisible", false);  
component.set("v.isVisible", true);
```

as its async in nature, by the time 1st callback is invoked, you are adding the element again, and hence 2nd callback will override 1st callback. So, although we have only 1 element in visible DOM, there are 2 references in `aura_prod.js`. Hence, this will return array.

**Solution**:

You can use `Array.isArray(component.find("question_answer"))` as below:

```
    let question_answer = null;
    if(Array.isArray(component.find("question_answer"))) {
        question_answer = component.find("question_answer")[0];
    } else {
        question_answer = component.find("question_answer");
    }

    // logic using question_answer
```

You need to be careful that you have unique `question_answer` in markup for above to work as expected.

> Or you should avoid implementing logic which will unrender and
>   rerender immediately.

**--- added based on comments -----**

When you are changing status to `Done`, it will be fine and works as expected. When you change status back to `Open`, you are running below code:

```
component.set("v.isVisible", false);  
component.set("v.isVisible", true);
```

After this point, `component.find('question_answer')` will be array and `component.find('question_answer').length` will return an integer and will not be undefined anymore. All the status changes henceforth will get `component.find('question_answer')` as array only

Comment: I had to write logic which rerenders picklist since there is no inbuilt method to remove error message on certain conditions.

Comment: But, why does `component.find("question_answer")` returns an array when Status is changed to 'Done' from 'Open' for the 2nd time even though there is only one item in `question_answer`.(I am referring  to `let quesLength = component.find('question_answer').length;`  line)

Comment: added in answer

Comment: added solution in top of answer